# Android - Passing variables to an already running IntentService

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

I have an IntentService which does some image processing. In my Activity, I have a cancel button which needs to send a message to the service (a boolean value) so that it should stop when it has finished processing the current image.

I know I can pass values to a service before calling startService() via the intent.putExtra() method. But in this case, I need to send the boolean variable to the IntentService while it's running.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Broadcasts, register a broadcast receiver in your service and send broadcast from your activity to the service.

Comment: `LocalBroadcastReceiver`, aye.